# Localization of text with a TagHelpers

Tags: asp.net-core, localization

I followed the guide at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization to translate a ASP.NET Core application.

But there are missing how to translate a text in a TagHelper like this:

```
Your password has been reset. Please <a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Click here to log in</a>.
```

In the github examples https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/dev/samples/Localization.StarterWeb/Views/Account/ResetPasswordConfirmation.cshtml these texts were omitted.

Thanks